# Aligning address on the same line, in 3-column style

Tags: resume, cv

I have been using example **res9a** [on this page](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/). As you can see, the address is divided into three lines. I am new to LaTeX, so not sure if this is possible, but can those three lines be put in one line, just in a 3-column layout style? For example, the first address line goes on the left, second in the center and third on the right?

I discussed this in the chat room and @egreg came up with this: `\noindent\makebox[\columnwidth][s]{Left\hfill\makebox{0pt}{Center}\hfill Right}` However, there is a weird indentation on the left side.

So is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can do, but keep in mind that this is quite dirty code:

```
% LaTeX resume using res.cls
\documentclass[margin]{res}
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} % set width of text portion

\begin{document}

% Center the name over the entire width of resume:
 \moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf Susan R. Bumpershoot}
% Draw a horizontal line the whole width of resume:
 \moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 1pt}\smallskip
% address begins here
% Again, the address lines must be centered over entire width of resume:
\moveleft\hoffset\hbox to \resumewidth{%
  1985 Storm Lane\hfill
  \makebox[0pt]{Troy, NY 12180}\hfill
  (518) 273-0014 or (518) 272-6666%
}


\begin{resume}

...

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The different right margins are due to the class and the top rule is as long as in the original example.

---

Here is a version that doesn't depend on the outdated `res` class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=6.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\pagestyle{empty}

\renewcommand\section[1]{%
  \item[\smash{\parbox[t]{1.4in}{\bfseries\raggedright#1}}]%
}
\newenvironment{resume}
 {\bigskip\begin{description}[leftmargin=1.5in,style=nextline]}
 {\end{description}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\large\bfseries Susan R. Bumpershoot\par}
\smallskip
% Draw a horizontal line the whole width of resume:
\hrule height 1pt
\smallskip
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
  1985 Storm Lane\hfill
  \makebox[0pt]{Troy, NY 12180}\hfill
  (518) 273-0014 or (518) 272-6666%
}
\end{center}

\begin{resume}

\section{OBJECTIVE}
A position in the field of computers with special
interests in business applications programming, 
information processing, and management systems. 


\section{EDUCATION}
\textsl{Bachelor of Science,} Interdisciplinary Science \\
Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, Troy, NY, 
expected December 1990 \\
Concentration: Computer Science \\
Minor: Management 


\section{COMPUTER \\ SKILLS}
\textsl{Languages \& Software:} COBOL, IFPS, Focus, 
Megacalc, Pascal, Modula2, C, APL, SNOBOL, 
FORTRAN, LISP, SPIRES, BASIC, VSPC Autotab, 
IBM 370 Assembler, Lotus 1-2-3. \\
\textsl{Operating Systems:} MTS, TSO, Unix. 


\section{EXPERIENCE}
\textsl{Business Applications Programmer} \hfill Fall 1990 \\
Allied-Signal Bendix Friction Materials Division, 
Financial Planning Department, Latham, NY 
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item Developed four ``user friendly'' forecasting 
systems each of which produces 18 to 139 
individual reports. 

\item Developed or improved almost all IFPS 
programs used for financial reports. 
\end{itemize}

\textsl{Research Programmer} \hfill Summer 1990 \\
Psychology Department, Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute 
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item Performed computer aided statistical analysis of data. 
\end{itemize} 
\textsl{Assistant Manager} \hfill Summers 1988-89 \\
Thunder Restaurant, Canton, CT
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item Recognized need for, developed, and wrote 
employee training manual. Performed various 
duties including cooking, employee training, 
ordering, and inventory control. 
\end{itemize} 

\section{COMMUNITY \\ SERVICE}
Organized and directed the 1988 and 1989 Grand 
Marshall Week \newline ``Basketball Marathon.'' A 24 hour 
charity event to benefit the Troy Boys Club. Over 
250 people participated each year. 

\section{EXTRA-CURRICULAR \\ ACTIVITIES} 
Elected \textit{House Manager}, Rho Phi Sorority \\
Elected \textit{Sports Chairman} \\
Attended Krannet Leadership Conference \\
Headed delegation to Rho Phi Congress \\
Junior varsity basketball team \\
Participant, seven intramural athletic teams 

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

[image]